Getting more details on branching Gurobi to Pyomo in SolverFactory
The software that I am developing is reading a parameter file, that contains 1) a "solver" input, which corresponds to the solver name that is used as first argument of the SolverFactory, and 2) a "executable" input that goes in as second argument in the SolverFactory.
import pyomo.environ as po
opt = po.SolverFactory(solver, executable=executable)


In the rest of the code I have defined my model (a ConcreteModel), which I then try to solve :
results = opt.solve(model)

My gurobi environment seems properly set (such as GUROBI_HOME, GRB_LICENSE_PATH).
When I am writing my solver="gurobi_direct", with the path to file "fullpath/gurobi_cl", the model is solved properly.
Whereas, when I am using "gurobi" (or "gurobi_persistent") I get a termination error: "Termination condition: unknown".
For information, the licence file (gurobi.lic) contains the address to my TokenServer, which is porperly managed when using gurobi out of Pyomo, or in Pyomo with gurobi_direct.
I am mostly wondering what difference in parameters is expected when using the different "gurobi" arguments ("gurobi" vs. "gurobi_direct" vs. "gurobi_persistent")
My model is properly written and works fine when using cplex or glpk.
In my environment, the package gurobipy==10.0.3 is also installed.
What should I do to make the solver work when calling simply "gurobi"?
Thank you so much in advance!

Is there any other output from Gurobi? Is the model solved at all? Why do you want to use a different way to run Gurobi via Pyomo if you already found a working solution?
